# How can I order my data as indicated?

Tags: sql, paraccel

Suppose I have some customer IDs and dates of transactions.

```
ID  DATE
1   OCT 1
1   OCT 2
1   OCT 3
1   OCT 31
```

What I would like is one column showing their previous transaction date, and another showing their next transaction date (shown below).

```
ID DATE1 DATE2
1  OCT 1  OCT 2
1  OCT2   OCT3
1  OCT 3  OCT 31
```

Here,`ID` is an INTEGER and `DATE` is a DATE.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Also, I assume the date column is really a date and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Most dialects of SQL support the ANSI standard window functions, including `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date is not null;
```

For databases that don't support this functionality, you can do something similar with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what database you're using you can simply select the results twice, both times with an enumerator column that tells the row number (for instance in T-SQL see how to use ROW_NUMBER()) , and then just join these two selects on a.enumerator = b.enumerator - 1